# Why isn't server side validation working in my ASP.Net MVC3 application with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation, server-side-validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application that uses entities generated from a database. Each entity has also has a separate partial class that uses the *MetadataType* attribute to associate each entity with a class that is decorated with a number of validation attributes (see below).

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Drawing.Metadata))]
public partial class Drawing
{
    private sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Drawing numbers must be between {2} and {1} characters in length.")]
        [DisplayName("Drawing number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Drawing titles must be between {2} and {1} characters in length.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Drawing drawing)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save to database here...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(drawing);
    }
}
```

I have used the Visual Studio templates to create the views to add, edit and delete the entities (The designer code has not been altered).

The problem I am having is that when I create an entity, validation only works if I have client side validation enabled. If I turn off the client side validation then *ModelState.IsValid* always seems to return true and returns me to the index page.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on how to get server side validation working with Entity Framework entities?

**UPDATE:**

It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6832843/577417) question is similar to mine. The author of this post seems to have solved the problem but rather unhelpfully omitted to mention *how* they fixed the problem...

Comment: Please show your code: model/controller/view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution to this problem. Because I didn't really want to set my properties to nullable I added the following:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

Adding the following annotation to your model property fixes the error as well.

Comment: +1 for answering a question despite the fact it already had an accepted answer. I have accepted this over my answer as this is a much better solution in my opinion (I also didn't really want to make my properties nullable). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation it seems that my problem is occuring due to a *ConstraintException* being thrown by my entity class (which inherits from *ObjectContext*) when the default model binder tries to bind the user input values (Null in this case) to the entity properties.

I can see 2 possible solutions to this:

1. Relax the constraints on my database tables (I don't want to do this).
2. Make the entity fields nullable (use the entity designer set the nullable property to yes)

I have used and tested the second option and can confirm that server side validation now works as expected.

Whilst researching solutions to this problem I have come to the conclusion that the problem is due to my entities inheriting from ObjectContext which is quite a heavy class. I found a lot of tutorials which used a code-first approach. In this case, the entity class will inherit from *DbContext* which is much more lightweight so I guess this could be considered a third solution to the problem.